# Validating a simple CSV file with double,double

Tags: c#, .net, validation, csv

In my program I want to import csv files that only should have a pair of doubles in them. Something like:

```
2.2131321321, 32.321321321
3.31321321321, 65.65454545
4.12321351351, 16.13211212
```

Can you help finding out a safe and fast way of doing so?

Comment: We don't "find" code at Stack Overflow. We help identify issues with your code. What is your issue?

Comment: How about you tell us what you tried, with code? We will not do your work for you, but help with any difficulties you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is read file line by line, split every line by `,` and try to parse each part using `double.TryParse`

Simple sample, assuming that file is valid (without check):

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<double, double>> ReadCSV(string filePath)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var split = line.Split(new[] { ',' },
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            yield return new Tuple<double, double>(
                double.Parse(split[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                double.Parse(split[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take caution when doing this, as decimal separator will depend on culture. Make sure to pass InvariantCulture.

Comment: @GeirGrusom +1 I've been bitten by the culture issue before.  It's not fun to deal with after the fact.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. But how it will be if a system has `,` as decimal separator so a line would be like `3,23565, 6,654654`

Comment: @Sean87, So you should use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`